# ArrayList is not behaving as expected in for loop

Tags: java, eclipse, for-loop, arraylist

```
import java.util.*;

public class elevator_EXPERIMENT {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Integer> UpArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> DownArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        int[] Floor = new int[12];
        for (int i = 0; i < Floor.length; i++) {
            Floor[i] = i + 1;
        }
        while (UpArrayList.size() != 8) {
            if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
                Random x = new Random();
                int UpRandom = (x.nextInt(11 - 1) + 1) + 1;
                Random x1 = new Random();
                int UpRandom1 = (x1.nextInt(11 - 1) + 1) + 1;
                if (UpRandom != UpRandom1 && !UpArrayList.contains(Floor[UpRandom])) {
                    UpArrayList.add(UpRandom1);
                }
            }
        }
        while (UpArrayList.size() != 8) {
            Random x = new Random();
            int UpRandom = (x.nextInt(11 - 1) + 1) + 1;
            while (UpArrayList.contains(Floor[UpRandom])) {

            }
        }
        System.out.print("Unsorted floors going up ");
        for (int i = 0; i < UpArrayList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(UpArrayList.get(i) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        while (DownArrayList.size() != 5) {
            if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
                Random y = new Random();
                int DownRandom = (y.nextInt(11 - 1) + 1) + 1;
                if (DownArrayList.contains(Floor[DownRandom])) {
                    Random y1 = new Random();
                    int DownRandom1 = (y1.nextInt(11 - 1) + 1) + 1;
                    if (DownRandom != DownRandom1 && !DownArrayList.contains(Floor[DownRandom1])) {
                        DownArrayList.add(DownRandom1);
                    }
                } else {
                    DownArrayList.add(Floor[DownRandom]);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print("\nUnsorted floors going down ");
        for (int i = 0; i < DownArrayList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(DownArrayList.get(i) + " ");
        }
        Collections.sort(UpArrayList);
        System.out.print("\n\n" + "Sorted floors going up ");
        for (int i = 0; i < UpArrayList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(UpArrayList.get(i) + " ");
        }
        Collections.sort(DownArrayList, Collections.reverseOrder());
        System.out.print("\n\n" + "Sorted floors going down ");
        for (int i = 0; i < DownArrayList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(DownArrayList.get(i) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            int floornumber = 1;
            System.out.println("\nStarting at floor " + floornumber);
            floornumber++;
            System.out.println("Going up: now at floor " + UpArrayList.get(floornumber));
            System.out.println("Stopping at floor " + UpArrayList.get(floornumber) + " for 3 seconds -> 1,2,3");
            SleepTimer(3000);
        }
    }

    public static void SleepTimer(int time) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(time);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong");
        }
    }
}
```

Hello, please look at the for loop above the SleepTimer method. I have two problems. My goal is to create an elevator txt simulator, elevator has 12 floors. I create two Arraylists: one that contains 8 random unique floors and one that contains 5 random unique floors labeled UpArrayList and DownArrayList respectively. I then sort them. Then I should create a txt prompt that is similar to something like this :

`2 3 4 6 7 8 10 11 Sorted ArrayList`

```
        Starting at floor 1
        Going up: now at floor 2
    Stopping at floor 2 for 3 seconds  1, 2, 3 

    Starting at floor 2 
        Going up: now at floor 3
    Stopping at floor 3 for 3 seconds  1, 2, 3

    Starting at floor 3 
        Going up: now at floor 4
    Stopping at floor 4 for 3 seconds  1, 2, 3

    Starting at floor 4 
        Going up: now at floor 5
        Going up: now at floor 6
     Stopping at floor 6 for 3 seconds  1, 2, 3

     Starting at floor 6
         Going up: now at floor 7
    Stopping at floor 7 for 3 seconds  1, 2, 3

     Starting at floor 7
         Going up: now at floor 8                                                                            
     Stopping at floor 8 for 3 seconds  1, 2, 3
```

Basically I want the format of the prompts from the for loop (at the end of the program) to say

```
Starting at Floor1
Going up: now at floor[FirstElementofUpArrayList]
Stopping at floor[FirstElementofUpArrayList" for 3 seconds -> 1,2,3
Starting at floor[SecondElementofUpArrayList]
Going up: now at floor[SecondElementofUpArrayList] for 3 seconds -> 1,2,3
```

until I get to the last element of the UpArrayList.

Comment: "*lease look at the for loop above the SleepTimer method*" - if you are having problems with only that part of the code, why include all of the rest?

Comment: Because I believe the elements of UpArrayList and how I've organized the Arraylist might be relevant towards providing people with context and how I need the forloop to function. I'm sorry if I didn't appropriately condense the question.

Comment: So you wrote a sample output and want us to provide a code that produces it? That's not how it works here

Comment: Again I apologize for not being as specific as I should be. I do not want the sample output, the sample output was there as an possible same output. What I want is what follows after "Basically I want the format of the prompts...to say" and the following 5 lines. I want to convert those 5 lines of english into something I can work with in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"ArrayList not behaving as expected in forloop"

It tells nothing, but looking at your implementation I guess that your problem is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException it is because size of your list is 8 and elements are indexed from 0 to 7. Last iteration of the last loop is calling for UpArrayList.get(8), but there is not 9th element.
Change

```
UpArrayList.get(floornumber);
```

to

```
UpArrayList.get(i);
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough, you're actually a saint. Thank you so much friend. 1.5hours beating my head against that block of code and couldn't figure it out.